# Default value for QCommandLineOption

Tags: default, qt6, qcommandlineparser

I'm working with `QCommandLineParser` but I'm not sure how to handle the `defaultValue` of an option. This is the snippet I have so far:

```
QCommandLineParser parser;
parser.setApplicationDescription("Video Grabber and Streamer");
parser.addOption(QCommandLineOption("streaming.fps", "Frame rate for streaming. Default: 20", "fps", "20"));
parser.process(*QCoreApplication::instance());
```

As far as I've understood from the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcommandlineoption.html#QCommandLineOption-3):

> In addition, the valueName needs to be set if the option expects a value. The default value for the option is set to defaultValue.

I'm expecting that if `--streaming.fps` option is not passed, the option will be present and set to `20`. But this does not happens; it works fine if I pass

```
myapp.exe --streaming.fps 10
```

`parser.optionNames()` contains `streaming.fps` and its value is 10. But if I run:

```
myapp.exe
```

Then `parser.optionNames()` is empty.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost 10 months old by now but i just struggled with this, so im answering it.

The `optionNames()` provides a list of option names **found** in the command line args. These do NOT include the names of options with a default value if the option was not passed in as a command line arg.

Note that you can still access the options with default values, so in the question, `parser.value("streaming.fps")` will be `20` when running `myapp.exe` even though `parser.optionNames()` will be empty.